# why does springframework's PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer fails to read the app.properties files

Tags: spring

I come across a strange problem and I have bean tryint to figure out it for three days, but still no result!

I have done the below configuration:

```
  <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>WEB-INF/conf/app.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>


  <bean id="commonDataSource" class="com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource" init-method="init"
      destroy-method="close"
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.common.driver}"
      p:url="${jdbc.common.url}"
      p:username="${jdbc.common.username}"
      p:password="${jdbc.common.password}"
      p:initialSize="${jdbc.common.pool.initsize}"
      p:minIdle="1"
      p:maxActive="20"
      p:maxWait="60000"
      p:timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="60000"
      p:minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="300000"
      p:validationQuery="SELECT 'x'"
      p:testWhileIdle="true"
      p:testOnBorrow="false"
      p:testOnReturn="false"
      p:poolPreparedStatements="false"
      p:maxPoolPreparedStatementPerConnectionSize="20"/>
```

the when I run the application in tomcat7 ,the problem come on,

```
严重: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commonMapperScannerConfigurer' defined in file [D:\IdeaProjects\git\bkk-web\target\bkk-web-1.0\WEB-INF\classes\spring\appContext-common.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'commonSqlSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commonSqlSessionFactory' defined in file [D:\IdeaProjects\git\bkk-web\target\bkk-web-1.0\WEB-INF\classes\spring\appContext-common.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'commonDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commonDataSource' defined in file [D:\IdeaProjects\git\bkk-web\target\bkk-web-1.0\WEB-INF\classes\spring\appContext-common.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'initialSize'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${jdbc.common.pool.initsize}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:116)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1553)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:622)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:569)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$254(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$2/2068728757.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commonSqlSessionFactory' defined in file [D:\IdeaProjects\git\bkk-web\target\bkk-web-1.0\WEB-INF\classes\spring\appContext-common.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'commonDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commonDataSource' defined in file [D:\IdeaProjects\git\bkk-web\target\bkk-web-1.0\WEB-INF\classes\spring\appContext-common.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'initialSize'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${jdbc.common.pool.initsize}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commonDataSource' defined in file [D:\IdeaProjects\git\bkk-web\target\bkk-web-1.0\WEB-INF\classes\spring\appContext-common.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'initialSize'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${jdbc.common.pool.initsize}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'initialSize'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${jdbc.common.pool.initsize}"
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${jdbc.common.pool.initsize}"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
    at org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor.setAsText(CustomNumberEditor.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:449)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:461)
    ... 83 more
```

how to figure it out ,can someone tell me, tks a lot!

Comment: Looks like you rpoperty files is not found. Change `<property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />` to <`property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false" />` and your program will stop if the file is not found

Answer (score 1):

Property file locations are classpath relative, you need to use `conf/app.properties` instead and make sure the file is under `WEB-INF/classes/conf/app.properties` in your assembly.

If you're using Maven the recommended location to place these files or directories is under `src/main/resources`. Maven will take care in its build process to copy the resources to the proper location which is the classpath root.